# Can I link multiple accounts with only one public token to exchange only one access token?

Tags: hyperlink, plaid

I am following the link flow which is things like:
create link token -> link from html page with the bank account that I chose -> get the public token from `onSuccess` event -> exchange access token.

However, I do want to use only one access token to manage all my accounts for API queries, is it possible to do so? If so, what's the step that I need to follow?

Thanks!

Tried the standard link flow but not working for multiple accounts bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A single public token can only be exchanged for a single access token, which gives access to a single Item.

Technically, one access token will control access to multiple accounts if the end user has multiple accounts at the same bank, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.

Comment: You are correct, I also created support ticket and got the same answer. So they support multiple account within one bank but not one access code to access all different bank accounts.